# Collect near polygons

Tags: postgis, polygon

I have the following data:

[image]

The data have 5 level (in tones blue). I want to collect only the nearest polygons with the same level and sum the number (represent client number). When I collect only for level I lose the number or client.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].